# How can I set default constraints on all my properties in hibernate validator

Tags: java, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I want to automatically put `@Valid` constraints on all my properties.

Example:

```
public class Adult extends MyBeanValidationAbstractClass{
    @Min(18)
    public Integer age;
    @NotBlank
    public String name;
    public Dog dog;
    public Cat cat;
}
```

I want the Validator to think that all properties have the `@Valid` annotation.

How can this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in you example, you want Dog and cat to be annotated with @Valid. I guess Integer and String should not be affected?
I dont think that you can automate this, who else but you should know, which requirements your attributes have?

--- Edit: just re-read ... you dont to write the annotations, you want to controll the Validator.

You could write a custom Constraint-Annoation for your type

```
@ValidAttributes
public class MyClass {
...
}
```

and then use a custome Validator for that annotation. Then you could use reflection to iterate over all your attributes and validate them.

Comment: The solution might be an constraints annotation on the class, or creating a custom validator

Comment: Not "or", "and". You will have to write your Constraint and the Validator.

Comment: my comment was for the before you edited the answer, this solution is good for me. But I am wondering if I can do this [Programmatic constraint definition](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/chapter-custom-options.html#programmaticapi)  that might look better

Comment: I only work with the JSR303 API of bean validation, I am not an expert of the internal hibernate-validator extensions. But from what I see, what you linked is not generic at all, looks more like a complete manual definition of all constraints. I guess, this is only useful if you dont want or can't annotate your Beans. 

You should consider writing "readable code". Anyone who has access to the Bean can see directly, that age has a min value of 18. That's very useful. Your "automatic" approach or the programmatic one you linked save you a few "@Valid" Annotations but at the cost of transparency.

Answer (score 0):

The honest answer is: bean validation is not following convention over configuration - you have to put @Valid all over the place. IMHO bean validation has a fundamental design flaw.

BTW: For those who don't like boilerplate code and want to go non-official ways have a look here:
https://m-m-m.github.io/maven/apidocs/net/sf/mmm/util/bean/api/Bean.html